# How do I install a keyboard layout indicator in awesome WM?

Tags: keyboard-layout, input-language

I have set up layout switching with

```
setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp_led:scroll,grp:ctrl_shift_toggle us,ru
```

which works, but there's no layout indication. How do I install a keyboard layout indicator in awesome WM?

Comment: Why is input language related to the window manager?

Comment: @DKBose I thought it does, because it worked in one, but not the other. Checking on this.

Comment: In Unity those xkb options are overridden by the *switch-input-source* key in the gsettings schema *org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings*. Maybe there is something similar in awesome.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Turns out, keyboard layout switching does not persist between sessions, rather than work in LXDE but not awesome. That should be a separate question (not related to awesome). Made this question to be about layout indicator instead. I hope that's ok.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about awesome, but giving this new info, I just posted an answer to your original problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

> This answer was written against a previous revision of the question, and is kept here for historical purposes.

You can make the settings persistent by editing `/etc/default/keyboard`.

So fot the layouts:

```
XKBLAYOUT="us,ru"
```

and for the switch options:

```
XKBOPTIONS="grp:switch,grp_led:scroll,grp:ctrl_shift_toggle"
```

Comment: The file is there, but it has no effect for some reason.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yes, I did reboot.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov: Can you please edit your question and show us what the command `setxkbmap -query` outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use new widget to set up your keyboard layouts: https://github.com/echuraev/keyboard_layout

Also, this widget supports "additional layouts". "Additional layouts" are those languages what you do not use very often but you need it from time to time.

For additional information, please, read description in the repository and see small screen casts how it works.